# How can I code a recursive search for linked database entities?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, recursion, search

I am building up a dynamic CDN for use internally at work. We have a vast number of web apps that us used in the business and are setting up a CDN so that all of the JS libraries (Bootstrap, Jquery,etc) live on. To aid in project creation, we have created a database where we have a table for the libraries, as well as a table for the library's requirements (i.e. Bootstrap requires Jquery). Using the data in the database on the requirements, a webAPI will return a List containing script tags and css link tags for use in _Layout.cshtml pages.

Database tables in question are tblLibrary & tblLibraryRequirements

The tblLibraryRequirements table consists of these columns:
- ID
- [Library ID]
- [Requires ID]

I have a working model which goes 3 levels deep, by nesting foreach loops to add the tblLibrary object of the requirement to a master list of all concerned libraries. Duplicates are removed via .Distinct()

```cs
        public ActionResult<List<string>> GetSciptTags_config(int ConfigID)
        {
            List<TblLibrary> LibraryRecsToScript = new List<TblLibrary>();

            // Get a list of libraries in the project config
            List<TblProjectConfigLibraries> configLibraries = db.TblProjectConfigLibraries.Where(s => s.ConfigurationId == ConfigID).ToList();

            foreach (TblProjectConfigLibraries configLibRec in configLibraries)
            {
                // get the tblLibrary record for the supplied ID
                TblLibrary libRec = db.TblLibrary.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == configLibRec.LibraryId);

                // find any requirement libraries
                List<TblLibraryRequirements> requirementRecs = db.TblLibraryRequirements.Where(s => s.LibraryId == configLibRec.LibraryId).ToList();

                foreach (TblLibraryRequirements item in requirementRecs)
                {
                    TblLibrary reqLibRec = db.TblLibrary.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == item.RequiresId);
                    // check that the requirement doesnt have requirements
                    List<TblLibraryRequirements> reqs = db.TblLibraryRequirements.Where(s => s.LibraryId == reqLibRec.Id).ToList();
                    foreach (TblLibraryRequirements req in reqs)
                    {
                        TblLibrary reqLibRec2 = db.TblLibrary.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == req.RequiresId);
                        LibraryRecsToScript.Add(reqLibRec2);
                    }
                    LibraryRecsToScript.Add(reqLibRec);
                }
                LibraryRecsToScript.Add(libRec);

            }

            // Remove Duplicates
            LibraryRecsToScript = LibraryRecsToScript.Distinct().ToList();
            // Get Scripts
            List<string> scripts = getScriptTags(LibraryRecsToScript);
            return scripts;
        }
```

The above works for the first 3 levels, but take a css library we have, which requires Bootstrap-DatePicker then I would want this to go as far back as JQuery.

-i.e. library1 depends on libraray2, which depends on library3, which depends on library4, etc

I'm sure there has to be a better way to do this but I'm failing at getting it straight in my head to code it out.

Any help is massively appreciated. Apologies for spelling, grammar, and format issues.

Comment: i'm not sure that is a good approach; you would also need to address the versioning, as one package is getting a new dependency starting on a specific version; why don't just host static files?

Comment: The files themselves are being hosted on this, the tblLibrary table has a name and a version as part of it's schema. The idea here is so that using a UI, a member of the team can select the libraries they want and the script tags get generated for them, including dependancies

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. It might not be as elegant as it could be, but it seems to work in my tests.

I have updated the controller Action to now call a function passing in the initial ID

```cs
 public ActionResult<List<string>> GetSciptTags_config(int ConfigID)
        {
            List<TblLibrary> LibraryRecsToScript = new List<TblLibrary>();

            // Get a list of libraries in the project config
            List<TblProjectConfigLibraries> configLibraries = db.TblProjectConfigLibraries.Where(s => s.ConfigurationId == ConfigID).ToList();

            foreach (TblProjectConfigLibraries configLibRec in configLibraries)
            {
                LibraryRecsToScript.AddRange(GetLibraryList(configLibRec.LibraryId));
            }

            // Get Scripts
            List<string> scripts = getScriptTags(LibraryRecsToScript);
            return scripts;
        }
```

This will then add the tblLibrary object to an external list called librariesSeen, and for each call, check to see if it has already been added to librariesSeen to stop infinite looping.

```cs
 private List<TblLibrary> GetLibraryList(int libraryID)
        {
            List<TblLibrary> retVal = new List<TblLibrary>();
            // master list of records found is a class wide variable so that this routine can be called from within itself
            TblLibrary libRec = db.TblLibrary.FirstOrDefault(s=> s.Id == libraryID);

            librariesSeen.Add(libRec);
            if (retVal.Contains(libRec) == false)
            {
                List<TblLibraryRequirements> requirementsFound = db.TblLibraryRequirements.Where(s => s.LibraryId == libraryID).ToList();
                foreach (TblLibraryRequirements req in requirementsFound)
                {
                    TblLibrary reqLibRecord = db.TblLibrary.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == req.RequiresId);
                    if (librariesSeen.Contains(reqLibRecord) == false)
                    {
                        retVal.AddRange(GetLibraryList(reqLibRecord.Id));
                    }
                }
                retVal.Add(libRec);

                // Remove Duplicates
                retVal = retVal.Distinct().ToList();
            }
            return retVal;
        }
```

Hope this helps someone else =)